# converting google datastore query result to pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I need to convert a Google Cloud Datastore query result to a dataframe, to create a chart from the retrieved data. The query:

```
def fetch_times(limit):
    start_date = '2019-10-08'
    end_date = '2019-10-19'
    query = datastore_client.query(kind='ParticleEvent')
    query.add_filter(
        'published_at', '>', start_date)
    query.add_filter(
        'published_at', '<', end_date)
    query.order = ['-published_at']
    times = query.fetch(limit=limit)
    return times
```

creates a json like string of the results for each entity returned by the query:

- Entity('ParticleEvent', 5942717456580608) {'gc_pub_sub_id': '438169950283983', 'data': '605', 'event': 'light intensity', 'published_at': '2019-10-11T14:37:45.407Z', 'device_id': 'e00fce6847be7713698287a1'}>

Thought I found something that would translate to json which I could convert to dataframe, but get an error that the properties attribute does not exist:

```
def to_json(gql_object):
    result = []
    for item in gql_object:
        result.append(dict([(p, getattr(item, p)) for p in item.properties()]))
    return json.dumps(result, cls=JSONEncoder)
```

Is there a way to iterate through the query results to get them into a dataframe either directly to a dataframe or by converting to json then to dataframe?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025095/pulling-data-from-datastore-and-converting-it-in-json-in-pythongoogle-appengine) is a similar post which will help you. This one is to [fetch JSON from Datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124781/how-to-properly-save-and-fetch-json-from-datastore)

Comment: Can you print in the console what's item and the whole gql_object, in order to provide a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Datastore entities can be treated as Python base dictionaries! So you should be able to do something as simple as...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(datastore_entities)
```

...and `pandas` will do all the rest.

If you needed to convert the entity `key`, or any of its attributes to a column as well, you can pack them into the dictionary separately:

```
for e in entities:
    e['entity_key'] = e.key
    e['entity_key_name'] = e.key.name  # for example

df = pd.DataFrame(entities)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.read_json` to read your json query output into a dataframe.

Assuming the output is the string that you have shared above, then the following approach can work.

```
#Extracting the beginning of the dictionary
startPos = line.find("{")

df = pd.DataFrame([eval(line[startPos:-1])])
```

Output looks like :

```
     gc_pub_sub_id data            event              published_at  \
0  438169950283983  605  light intensity  2019-10-11T14:37:45.407Z   

                  device_id  
0  e00fce6847be7713698287a1
```

Here, `line[startPos:-1]` is essentially the entire dictionary in that sthe string input. Using `eval`, we can convert it into an actual dictionary. Once we have that, it can be easily converted into a dataframe object

Comment: Thanks for the input.   The query output is not true json, but similar in that it is {keyword: value}.

Comment: Could you provide some sample of the data then? Without the proper format of how the data looks like, it’s difficult to give an exact solution

Comment: i included an example query output above  ```Entity('ParticleEvent', 5942717456580608) {'gc_pub_sub_id': '438169950283983', 'data': '605', 'event': 'light intensity', 'published_at': '2019-10-11T14:37:45.407Z', 'device_id': 'e00fce6847be7713698287a1'}```

Comment: I have found a (rather dirty) workaround.  I convert each item in the query result object to string, and then manually parse the string to extract the data I need into a list.  Now looking again at the output, i may have been able to clip off the header portion of the item : ```Entity('ParticleEvent', 5942717456580608)``` which would leave just the (key: value).  Then it may be recognized as json to convert more easily.

Comment: Could you please post your workaround solution as an answer for greater visibility to other community users? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Original poster found a workaround, which is to convert each item in the query result object to string, and then manually parse the string to extract the needed data into a list.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of the `fetch` function is `google.cloud.datastore.query.Iterator` which behaves like a `List[dict]` so the output of `fetch` can be passed directly into `pd.DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(fetch_times(10))
```

This is similar to @bkitej, but I added the use of the original poster's function.